# Metro Style App MFT "Class Not Registered" Error

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, ms-media-foundation

I am currently designing an app with the Metro app framework which includes a live video chat feature. I am using the GrayscaleTransform MFT included in the MediaCapture sample (at this point simply copy-and-pasted from the sample).

However, when I try to add the grayscale effect to the camera's image stream, I get a "class not registered" fatal error. I understand this is because I must 'activate and register' the media extension, but I do not know how. **How do I register the media extension?**

All help is greatly appreciated and I always accept an answer!

UPDATE: My GrayScale IDL file is shown below:

```
import "Windows.Media.idl";

#include <sdkddkver.h>

namespace GrayscaleTransform
{
[version(NTDDI_WIN8), activatable(NTDDI_WIN8)]
runtimeclass GrayscaleEffect 
{
    [default] interface Windows.Media.IMediaExtension;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The media extension is specified as an `<Extension>` (or extensibility point) in the package manifest's [Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211401.aspx) section, but you need to insert it manually (i.e. open the appxmanifest as code instead of double-clicking.)

Using the GrayscaleTransform example, in the [Media extensions sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Media-extensions-sample-7b466096), open the MediaExtensions project's package.appxmanifest (as code) and look for this in the `<Extensions>` section:

```
<Extension Category="windows.activatableClass.inProcessServer">
    <InProcessServer>
        <Path>GrayscaleTransform.dll</Path>
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="GrayscaleTransform.GrayscaleEffect" ThreadingModel="both" />
    </InProcessServer>
</Extension>
```

There's a bit more general info on extensions in [App contracts and extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464906.aspx).

Comment: Hand editing of the Extensions should not usually be required:  if you have a reference to a project or an extension SDK, the build will automatically add Extension elements for each activatable class in the referenced project or extension SDK.  The problem here appears to be that the MediaExtensions classes are not annotated with [activatable] in the IDL, so they are not attributed with ActivatableAttribute in their respective WinMDs.  This is a bit peculiar.

Comment: While this solution DOES work, it does seem odd that I need to directly edit the manifest file to get it to work. I'll accept this answer tomorrow if I haven't found a better solution by then.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same task, however, I don't want to have that extra DLL (GrayscaleTransform.dll). So, I copied all files from that dll project to my main dll, however it does not work. Is there anything that I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

As Chris Bowen explains in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11731680/151292), your application's AppXManifest is missing the required Extension elements for the activatable classes in the media extensions modules.  All (non-Windows-provided) activatable classes need to be listed in the AppXManifest.  The solution of adding the Extension nodes to the AppXManifest yourself will work, and this is what the MediaExtensions sample applications appear to have done.

However, you should not normally need to hand-edit the list of extensions.  If you add a reference to a Windows Runtime Component project, a loose WinMD file, or an extension SDK, the build should automatically generate Extension elements for each of the activatable classes in the referenced components.

The reason this is not happening is that the media extensions are not annotated with the [activatable] attribute in IDL, so they are not attributed with the ActivatableAttribute in the WinMD that is generated.  Instead of hand-editing the AppXManifest, you can declare the type as activatable in its IDL definition.

For example, to update `GeometricSource.GeometricSchemeHandler`, you can change its definition in IDL from:

```
[version(NTDDI_WIN8)]
runtimeclass GeometricSchemeHandler
{
}
```

to:

```
[version(NTDDI_WIN8), activatable(NTDDI_WIN8)]
runtimeclass GeometricSchemeHandler
{
    [default] interface Windows.Media.IMediaExtension;
}
```

Note the added `activatable` attribute and the  added `[default]` interface.  If you make these changes to each of the extensions and clean/rebuild, you should not need to explicitly specify the activatable types in your AppXManifest:  the build system will add them automatically.

Comment: I have tried the above, but I still get the "class not registered" error, even after cleaning and rebuilding the solution. I updated my question with my IDL file. I don't know if its relevant, but I also don't have a WinMD file.

Comment: The GrayscaleTransform project produces a .winmd file as part of its build.  If you reference the project from your application, that WinMD file should also be packaged in with your app when you Deploy it.

Comment: I see. But why isn't the extension being added to the manifest when the solution is built?

Comment: Note that the build will not modify the Package.AppXManifest file in the project.  It only modifies the generated AppXManifest.xml, which is created when you deploy the app (usually under the solution's Debug\ProjectName\AppX folder).  If the type is not present in that file, open the WinMD for GreyscaleTransform in ildasm: does the GrayscaleEffect type have the ActivatableAttribute attribute?

Comment: @JamesMcNellis What if the code from GrayscaleTransform is copied to my main native dll (that is supposed to use that GrayscaleTransform thing)? It forks for me as long as the GrayscaleTransform is a standalone dll